# python check_output FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running the next piece of code to check the type of my file:

```
import subprocess as sub
output = sub.check_output(["file", "test.py"]).decode('ascii')   
#output=sub.check_output(["file","C:/Users/Roger.That/PycharmProjects/test/test.py"]).decode('ascii')
```

and I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Roger That/PycharmProjects/test/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    output = sub.check_output(["file", "test.py"]).decode('ascii')
  File "C:\Users\Roger That\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\Roger That\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Roger That\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Roger That\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The full path of my test.py : `"C:/Users/Roger.That/PycharmProjects/test/test.py"`

output from gitbash :

```
$ file /c/Users/Roger\ That/PycharmProjects/test/test.py
/c/Users/Roger That/PycharmProjects/test/test.py: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Any chance that it is related to the fact that I have a dot between "Roger" and "That"? Although it doesn't work also when I use the relative path (only the file name)

### Update

I changed my user's dir name from `Roger that` to `Roger.that`, but it still didn't help:

```
python /c/Users/Roger.That/PycharmProjects/test/test.py
same error..
```

checked also :

```
import subprocess as sub
output = sub.check_output(["ls" "-l"])
```

got same error

Comment: You seem to be trying to run an executable named "file" and there is no such file.

Comment: @zvone I have gitbash installed and I can use the file command. I didnt use shell=True so I guess it should work..

Comment: "file" may be in gitbash path, but not in windows cmd path.

Comment: why don't you simply run your script using `python` rather than relying on `file`? like this: `sub.check_output([sys.executable, "test.py"])`

Comment: my goal is  to analyze the output of the file command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created from scratch the virtual environment and it solved my problem.